# Apollo-Client field policy: using readField handle for fields with arguments

Tags: apollo-client

When defining a field `read` policy in Apollo-Client's cache, does anybody know if it's possible to use `readField` handle to read values of fields with arguments?

E.g., I have the following object in my cache:

```
parent {
   id
   child({"arg1"="A"})
   child({"arg1"="B"})
}
```

I need to set a read policy on a `child` field of `parent` to handle those cases when a second argument (e.g., `arg2`) is passed to that field. In other words, I need to read `child({"arg1"="A","arg2"=true})` (not present in cache) based off of the value of `child({"arg1"="A"})` (present in cache). E.g.:

```
read(cached, { readField, args }){
   if(!args?.arg2) return cached;
   const cachedWithoutArg2 = ???
   return doSomething(cachedWithoutArg2);
}
```

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to the party, but you can use the extended version of `readField` to pass arguments to that specific read -> `readField({ fieldName: 'child', args: { arg1 })`